# C# MVC - Passing a method to my HomeController index and using it in my front end

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

> // this method i have in my controller right now. just trying to pass
>   it into my index.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

       var tenYears = ViewBag.GetYears(10);

        return View(tenYears);
    }



private List<int> GetYears(int yearRange)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-yearRange).Year, 
        yearRange).ToList();
    }
```

```html
> I am trying to use a foreach on my passed parameter from my Index HomeController

<div id="checkboxes" class="grid-container2">
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.yearRange[0]</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years1</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years2</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years3</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years4</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years5</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years6</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years7</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years8</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years9</label>
                <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @ViewBag.years10</label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Yes i need a list of the past ten years and i just need to be able to iterate through them and use each year for a different check box in the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want list of previous years, then You can use [`Enumerable.Range()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netcore-3.1),

```
using Systems.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

...
//Pass year range
private List<int> GetYears(int yearRange)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-yearRange).Year, yearRange).ToList();
}
```

To access individual elements in list, you can use indexes (starting from zero)

[.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pn74k9)

---

To iterate over List in view, you can try below

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.yearRange)
{
    <label><input id="chkBoxYear" type="checkbox" name="Year" value=""> @item </label>
}
```

Comment: How would i go about passing that to my Index Controller? Then would i use yearRange[0] in my front end to iterate? Would i need to use a foreach?

Comment: Index controller? do you mean to say any endpoint in then index controller as a parameter? Would I need to use a foreach?  -> Yes you need to use foreach loop to iterate over individual element in the list. You can update your current question with detailed information about above questions or you can ask separate questions.